# what is the n number of file descriptors after which it is best to switch to epoll over poll?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, polling, epoll

Do we have any benchmarks for a range of descriptors from 1 to 50 or so? Most benchmarks I see are for large number of descriptors 100s..1000s...

I am currently using poll with 16 descriptors and thinking of using epoll if that will improve speed of app.

```
Please advise in 3 scenarios with 16 socket descriptors in the set for poll/epoll:
1. most of the sockets are active...>both should be same performance?
2. half active half idle....what is better here?
3. mostly idle...> clearly epoll is better ?
```

Comment: With only 16 descriptors I'd be astonished if there was any difference at all. You would need hundreds or thousands. Do you have any evidence that `poll()` is your present bottleneck?

Comment: @EJP I didnt hit any bottleneck. Just was thinking if I can squeeze a bit more performance if I switched to epoll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would very much suspect that switching from `poll()` to `epoll()` will not make any difference in the performance of your application. The main advantage of `epoll()` crops up when you have many file descriptors (hundreds or thousands) where a standard `poll()` requires a little more work to be done on every call, whereas `epoll()` does the setup in advance - as long as you don't change the set of file descriptors you're watching, each call is very slightly quicker. But generally this difference is only noticeable for many, many file descriptors.

Bear in mind that if the set of file descriptors you're watching changes very frequently, `epoll()`'s main advantage is lost because you still need to do the work of passing new file descriptors into the kernel. So, if you're handling lots of short-lived connections then it's even less compelling to switch to it.

Another difference is that `epoll()` can be **edge-triggered**, where the call only returns when *new* activity occurs on a descriptor, or **level-triggered**, where the call returns while the descriptor is read/write-ready. The standard `poll()` call is *always* level-triggered. For most people, however, level-triggered is what they want - edge-triggered interfaces are occasionally useful, but in most cases they lead to race conditions where data arrives on a socket after reading but before entering the `epoll()` call. My advice is stay well away from edge-triggered code unless you really, really know what you're doing.

The price you pay for `epoll()` is the lack of portability - both `poll()` and `select()` are standard POSIX interfaces, so your code will be much more portable by using them. The `epoll()` call, on the other hand, is only available on Linux. Some other Unix variants also have their own equivalent mechanisms, such as kqueue on FreeBSD, but you have to write different code for each platform in that case.

My advice is until you reach a point where you're using many file descriptors, don't even worry about `epoll()` - seriously, there are almost certainly many other places in your code to make far bigger performance improvements and it's entirely possible that `epoll()` may not be faster for your use-case anyway.

If you do reach a stage where you're handling many connections and the rest of your code is already pretty optimal then you should first consider something like [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) which is a cross-platform interface which uses the best performance calls on each particular platform. It [performs very well](http://libev.schmorp.de/bench.html) and it's probably rather less hassle overall than directly using `epoll()` even if you only want to support Linux.

I haven't referred to the three scenarios you mention so far because I don't believe any of them will perform any differently for a low number of file descriptors such as 16. For a large number of file descriptors, `epoll()` should outperform `poll()` particularly where there are mostly idle file descriptors. If all file descriptors are always active, both calls require iterating through every connection to handle it. However, as the proportion of idle connections increases, `epoll()` gives better performance as it only returns the active connections - with `poll()` you still have to iterate through everything and most of them will be skipped, but `epoll()` returns you only the ones you need to handle (up to a maximum limit you can specify).

To spell that out explicitly (and this is *only* relevant for large numbers of connections, as I mentioned above):

1. Most of the sockets are active: *Both calls broadly comparable, perhaps `epoll()` still slightly ahead.*
2. Half active half idle: *Would expect `epoll()` to be somewhat better here.*
3. Mostly idle: *Would expect `epoll()` to definitely be better here.*

**EDIT:**

You might like to see [this graph](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/libevent-benchmark.jpg) which is from the libevent author and shows the relative overhead of handling an event as the number of file descriptors changes. Note how all the lines are converging around the origin, demonstrating that all the mechanisms achieve comparable performance for a small number of descriptors.